# Stopping Power in quantum mechanical models

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

How is stopping power accounted for in a wave function for a particle? Is there an associated potential with stopping power that needs to be accounted for, or something else?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_power_(particle_radiation)  it seems to be various ways in nuclear physics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_power_(particle_radiation)  that particles interact with matter. If you read the article you will see that it is modeled with existing  quantum mechanical models for particles through matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean the stopping power of the medium that the particle is interacting with. This stopping power is a statistical property of the dynamic evolution of the particle in a large number of elementary interactions with the medium. Thus it is not expressed in the wave function alone, but is a complex interplay of quantum properties of the particle, such as the electric or the color charge, and charge and mass densities of the medium.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is the stopping power itself a description of the state of the particle, or does the wave function combined with the stopping power describe the particle's state or neither? Is it similar to how friction (another resisting force) is added on to an equation of motion in classical mechanics?

Comment: The stopping power is not a description of the state of the particle, but rather a property of the medium with respect to a given **type** of particle. You could say that the wave function combined with the stopping power defines the expected dynamical evolution of the state of the particle in the medium.